# ValueError: Cannot use 'Enter' as input to 'Merge' because 'Enter' is in a while loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Problem occured when I use tf.nn.dynamic_rnn,I don't quite understand what does this 'Enter' and 'Merge' mean in this context. Hope you can help me, thanks!

```
# here is python code
value, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstmCell, wordvec_tensor, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Here is the [error log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHnyh.png)

Comment: I did two things for getting out of this trouble, I was using attention and hadn't defined cell before calling attention wrapper, silly mistake.